# Howto use ppl tasks and .then in a loop?

Tags: c++, concurrency, ppl

Im trying to learn ppl. Instead of using threads. Lets take it from the beginning. I have this simple problem:

v1:

```
            while(true)
            {
                auto important_msg = ReceiveImportantMessage_Blocking(); //Blocks for about 20s until there is a new message
                //do processing on important_msg
                auto unimportant_msg = ReceiveUnimportantMessage_Blocking(); //Blocks for about 60s until there is a new message
                //do processing on unimportant_msg
            }
```

v1 is obviously bad as both these calls will block and end up waiting for eachother.

v2:

```
            while(true)
            {
                auto important_msg = ReceiveImportantMessage_Blocking(); //Blocks for about 20s until there is a new message
                //do processing on important_msg
                auto unimportant_msg = CheckForUnimportantMessage_NonBlocking(); //works by polling queue. Returns empty if no message
                if(unimportant_msg) {
                    //do processing on unimportant_msg
                }
            }
```

v2 is better as the unimportant message will not block the important message. Also the important message gets processed the instance after it is  received. The unimportant messages though dont get checked before we have received a important message. So the unimportant message might be 20s old by the time I get to it.

v3:

```
            while(true)
            {
                auto important_msg = CheckForImportantMessage_NonBlocking(); //works by polling queue. Returns empty if no message
                if(important_msg) {
                    //do processing on important_msg
                }   
                auto unimportant_msg = CheckForUnimportantMessage_NonBlocking(); //works by polling queue. Returns empty if no message
                if(unimportant_msg) {
                    //do processing on unimportant_msg
                }
                sleep(10); //just so we don't busy wait.    
            }
```

v3 gets unimportant messages quicker. But its also slower for important messages. The processing of important messages doesnt happen at once they are received. But only when I get around to check for it. As I added a sleep to avoid busy waiting (and consuming too much cpu time), important messages will take longer to get received and processed than with v2.

v4:

```
            {
                auto important_msg_task = ReceiveImportantMessageTask_NonBlocking(); //ppl::task
                auto unimportant_msg_task = ReceiveUnimportantMessageTask_NonBlocking(); //ppl::task
                while(true)
                {
                    if(important_msg_task.is_done()) {
                        auto important_msg = important_msg_task.get();
                        //do processing on important_msg
                        important_msg_task = ReceiveImportantMessageTask_NonBlocking(); //listen for new message
                    }
                    if(unimportant_msg_task.is_done()) {
                        auto unimportant_msg = unimportant_msg_task.get();
                        //do processing on important_msg
                        unimportant_msg_task = ReceiveUnimportantMessageTask_NonBlocking(); //listen for new message
                    }
                    sleep(10); //just so we don't busy wait.    
                }
            }
```

V4 is the same as v3. Just with ppl tasks instead. It has the problem of not processing important messages at once the are received.

v5)
I'd like to remove the sleep and use important_msg_task ".then" to fire off processing once it is received, and ".then" listen for a new message once the old message is processed, and ".then" process the new message and so on (and do the same for unimportant_msg_task). I don't know how this can be done inside a loop. It seems I would just end up with an ever growing chain of connected tasks one after another forever.

So how do you solve this problem with ppl (or at least without raw threads)?

Comment: Seems looping and tasks don't go well together. You have to use recursion or "Create_iterative_task" as explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/05/09/how-to-put-a-ppltasks-continuation-chain-into-a-loop.aspx

Comment: Seems pplawait.h with __await and __resumable is simpler and cleaner building blocks. Much like what C# has already. I'll look into it.

Comment: I ended up using when_any from "PPL Power Pack" https://pplpp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Heterogeneous%20when_any

Comment: for what its worth the power pack when_any works, but it seems to cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

Use this kinda idiomatic code:

```cpp
template<typename Func>
concurrency::task<void> doWhile(Func func)
{
  static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<decltype(func()), bool> ||
    std::is_same_v<decltype(func()), concurrency::task<bool>>);

  return concurrency::create_task(func)

    .then([func](bool needToContinue)
    {
      if (needToContinue)
        return doWhile(func);

      return concurrency::task_from_result();
    });
}
```

In your case for one task you can write something like this:

```cpp
concurrency::task<bool> process() {
  // launching initial task
  auto important_msg_task = ReceiveImportantMessageTask_NonBlocking(); //ppl::task

  // adding continuation with processing of the result
  auto continuation = important_msg_task.then([](const Message &msg)
  {
    // do processing on important msg

    // decide whether to continue or stop processing
    return stopProcessing() ? false : true;
  });

  return continuation;
}

auto loop = doWhile([] {
  return process();
});
```

Use `loop.get()` to wait till the processing finishes.

To have two parallel processing "loops", just fire the second `doWhile` for the other "loop", e.g. like this:

```cpp
auto loop2 = doWhile([] {
  return ReceiveUnimportantMessageTask_NonBlocking()
    .then([](const Message &msg)
    {
      //do processing on unimportant msg
      return !stopProcessing();
    });
});
```

Since all the tasks are executed on a thread pool, having several `doWhile`s effectively makes the processing parallel.